# Android How to protect an application from being removed when user hard reset the device

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin

I looked a lot for a solution to protect an application from being removed after hard reset a device like a system app such as youtube play store Gmail, etc...

Comment: Are you making a custom ROM? Because what you're requesting sounds a lot like malware. If this were doable, it would be really bad for Android users.

Comment: i did not understand what u mean

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. There is a difference between Youtube, Gmail, and other apps that come preinstalled on your phone than any other app. These apps are part of Android OS because they are part of Google Services.

Equivalent to this question would be for you to ask to get Chrome or Steam preinstalled when you first run your freshly installed version of Windows OS/Ubuntu OS on your PC. I am pretty sure that's not possible.

Anyway, I think you should read some of the rules from Stackoverflow because I think this question is not in line with the rules.

Answer (score 0):

It is **impossible**. Otherwise it would be a gateway for all kind of malware software.